# How to find 5 closest points based on cosine distance in S from P

Tags: python-3.x

Consider you are given n data points in the form of list of tuples like S=[(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4),(x5,y5),..,(xn,yn)] and a point P=(p,q) 
your task is to find 5 closest points(based on cosine distance) in S from P

Ex:
S= [(1,2),(3,4),(-1,1),(6,-7),(0, 6),(-5,-8),(-1,-1)(6,0),(1,-1)]
P= (3,-4)

I have tried with below code

```
import math

data = [(1,2),(3,4),(-1,1),(6,-7),(0, 6),(-5,-8),(-1,-1)(6,0),(1,-1)]
data.sort(key=lambda x: math.sqrt((float(x.split(",")[0]) - 3)**2 +
                                  (float(x.split(",")[1]) -(-4))**2))
print(data)
```

I should get 5 closest points in S from P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have a missing comma in the defenition of `data`
- You have a list of tuples but for some reason you used `split` as if it was a list of strings.

If you fix these 2 errors it works. You just need to grab the first 5 elements from `data`:

```
import math

data = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (-1, 1), (6, -7), (0, 6), (-5, -8), (-1, -1), (6, 0), (1, -1)]
data.sort(key=lambda x: math.sqrt((float(x[0]) - 3) ** 2 +
                                  (float(x[1]) - (-4)) ** 2))
print(data[:5])
```

Outputs

```
[(1, -1), (6, -7), (-1, -1), (6, 0), (1, 2)]
```

(Next time, if you get an error please explain it in your question)

Answer (score 0):

```
cosine_dist = []

for a, b in S:

    num = a * P[0] + b * P[1]
    den = math.sqrt(a * a + b * b) * math.sqrt(P[0] * P[0] + P[1] * P[1])
    cosine_dist.append(math.acos(num/den))
X = cosine_dist
Y = [S for S in sorted(zip(S,X), key=lambda i:i[1])]
k = Y[:5] 
for i, j in k:
    print(i)
```

P = (3, -4)
S = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (-1, 1), (6, -7), (0, 6), (-5, -8), (-1, -1), (6, 0), (1, -1)]

Comment: You should provide some explanations with your code so we can easily understand what it does.

Comment: The code implements the cosine distance formula to calculate 5 closest points  in S to a query point P.  X has calculated all distances from each point in S to P.                  And then Y simply maps the points to the respective points in an ascending order. K selects the smallest 5 distances stored in Y.

Comment: In your answer not in the comment